# How to show thumbnail in VideoView if video from Raw android

Tags: android

I want to play a video in VideoView with a play button on the view.

But what I need is to show a Thumbnail of video to be played in VideoView.
I tried these line of code to show thumbnails in VideoView

```
 String path = "android.resource://com.example.app/"+R.raw.intro_video;
 Bitmap thumbAsBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
 BitmapDrawable thumbAsDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(thumbAsBitmap);
                      mVideoView.setBackgroundDrawable(thumbAsDrawable);
 mVideoView.setBackgroundDrawable(thumbAsDrawable);
 mVideoView.pause();
```

Exactly the same line of code is working perfectly fine when I try to play a video from
sd-card but when I try it from Raw folder it doesn't work.
Plz help me out.. 
Thanx in advance..